# Как в Python узнать, какой элемент первее попадается в строчке?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Нужно узнать, какой элемент первее попадается в строке.

Например:

"Ага, типа того"

И нужно сделать условие, что первее: "Ага" или "того"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть два варианта поиска. Через регулярные выражения и метод строки `find()`.
Вариант через регулярные выражения:

```
import re

text = "Привет. Ага, типа того"
finds = re.findall(r'(\bага\b|\bтого\b)', text, re.IGNORECASE)
print('Раньше встречается {}'.format(finds[0]))
```

Другой вариант, когда результат вычисляется через метод строки `find()`, возвращающий позиции искомых слов.Дальше сортируем и выдаем первое упоминание.

У этого метода минус, что он найдет `ага` и как отдельное слово, так и как составляющую слова.

```
text = "Привет. Ага, типа того"
req = ['ага', 'того']
positions = [(r, text.lower().find(r)) for r in req]
print('Раньше встречается {} на позиции {}'.format(*(sorted(positions, key=lambda x: x[1]))[0]))
```

Comment: А, понял, спасибо.  Просто пытался уже искать, но не нашёл. Решил сюда опубликовать свой метод

Comment: Обновил пост. Добавил по регуляркам вариант. Плюс дополнил по `find()`

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "Ага, типа того"
a=[] #Список для засчитывания
count_a = 0 #Переменная, которая считает сколько раз повторялось "ага"
count_b = 0 #Переменная, которая считает сколько раз повторялось "того"
for i in text.split():
    if i == "ага":
        if count_a == 0:
            a.append(i)
        count_a += 1
    if i == "того":
        if count_b == 0:
            a.append(i)
        count_b += 1

print(a)

>>> ['ага', 'того']
```

Осталось только сделать условие на место элемента в списке: первее он или нет

Пример:

```
if a[0] == "ага":
    #Код
if a[1] == "того":
    #Код
```

Comment: А зачем `re.search` импортировали? Если ее не используете. Ей тоже можно найти первое включение

Comment: Первая версия кода была другой. Забыл убрать. Спасибо